# Wrong emptyset symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Each time i type `$\emptyset$` an ugly (if I may say so, I think it's ugly), or rather unexpected  slashed circle comes out instead of the (expected) emptyset. I want my `\emptyset`! What should I do?

The packages that I use are:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amscd, amssymb, latexsym,amstext,amsthm}  
\usepackage[all]{xy}  
\usepackage{textcomp}  
\usepackage{mathabx}  
%\usepackage{MnSymbol}  
\usepackage{newlfont}  
%\usepackage{eufrak}  
\usepackage{bussproofs}  
\input{nprooftree.tex}  
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage{pifont}   
\usepackage{verbatim}    
\usepackage{cmll}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{tikz-cd}  
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
```

Comment: Can you show us a picture of this "ugly [beast]"?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `\varnothing`? (Provided by `amssymb`.)

Comment: @ Werner It's too ugly! (I don't know how to do that ), however, it looks like \varnothing but bigger, say the size of a capital letter.

Comment: Is it like a zero in shape or is it really a circle? Because, by default, `\emptyset` gives you a thin symbol and `\varnothing` gives you a fatter one which is a circle.

Comment: Can you post a minimal document `\documentclass...` which produces the symbol you don't like? Then we can at least figure out what you are getting and want to change.

Comment: That's the default `\emptyset`. Note that your request seems very subjective, as beauty is relative. `\emptyset` is normal and good-looking to me, in context.

Comment: @ cfr I created a new document like you sai, with no exstra commands, and I got the beautiful emptyset.

Comment: @ cfr I guess one of the packages that I use in my current document modify the emptyset. I'll include the list.

Comment: @ Warner You are absolutly right about the relative beaty. Yet my Professor (and I) want the thin emptyset.

Comment: Remove, as soon as possible, the loading of `newlfont`: it's an obsolete package that's provided only for compatibility with older documents. No document written after 1994 should use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `mathabx` to restore the default `\emptyset`.

Comment: @ cfr It looks like only the emptyset has changed. Thank you.

Comment: @Guest I really recommend pruning the font packages you are loading. Things are likely to produce weirdly confusing results. At least make sure you know *why* you are loading each one and make sure you really need to.